# Opencart Indirect modification of overloaded property

Tags: php, opencart

i'm getting below error on payment success page on opencart.

```
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ModelCheckoutOrder::$data has no effect in /srv/www/example.com/public_html/catalog/model/checkout/order.php on line 500
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ModelCheckoutOrder::$data has no effect in /srv/www/example.com/public_html/catalog/model/checkout/order.php on line 501
```

Those 500 & 501 lines are,

```
$this->data['payment_firstname'] = $order_info['payment_firstname'];
$this->data['payment_lastname'] = $order_info['payment_lastname'];
```

If i refresh the page it's disappearing. Any idea why this error appearing ?

Comment: which payment gateway are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model files don't have a `$data` property. That's controllers. This is the reason you are getting this error as the code is trying to set a value to a property that doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

First you hv to create that property .
eg. during validations , at the top of your class declare:

```
private $error = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 
Code:

> $this->data

To 
Code:

> $data

Answer (score -1):

```
$data['payment_firstname'] = $order_info['payment_firstname'];
$data['payment_lastname'] = $order_info['payment_lastname'];
```

Comment: Answers usually include some description as to how you arrived at the answer. this makes it more useful for other users as well